# jQuery: Element still ":hidden" after .slideDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element I want to start hidden using CSS `display: none;`, `slideDown()` to visible on the `click()` of a button, and finally `slideUp()` back to hidden on the `click()` of the same button.

Seems like it should be easy and simple to implement but it wasn't working, and I found that it's because the `element:hidden` property seems to be remaining `true` even after `slideDown()`.

Here's the CSS:

```
#event-form {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

And here's the script:

```
$('#create-new').click(function() {
    if ($('#event-form:hidden')) {
        $('#event-form').slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $('#event-form').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `if ($('#event-form:hidden')) { }` is returning true regardless of whether anything is selected. To check if the element is hidden, you could either use the `.is()` method (which will return a Boolean):

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/3upxfhb9/)

```
$('#event-form').is(':hidden')
```

or check the length of the jQuery object:

```
$('#event-form:hidden').length
```

---

You could also just use the `.slideToggle()` method:

```
$('#create-new').click(function() {
    $('#event-form').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: You have explained very well. I am voting your answer up.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `display: none` from the CSS and hide it using JavaScript:

```
$("#event-form").hide();
```

Instead of `:hidden` change it to:

```
if ($('#event-form').is(':hidden')) {
```

Comment: Kept the "display: none" but used $('#event-form').is(':hidden')

Comment: Praveen Kumar, why remove `display: none`? You didn't explain anything in your answer.

Comment: @JoshCrozier It's okay. You have explained very well. I am voting your answer up.